# xml data not showing in flash movie

Tags: xml, flash

I know this has been asked already.  But the solution given is not working.

I have a page.php with a flash banner embeded.  banner.swf loads, but displays nothing because it is not getting its data from data.xml which is in flash/lighter/data.xml

It only works if the banner.swf and data.xml and the banner_images are all in the root directory.  That's not possible and totally unacceptable.  So I did get some info here about setting a parameter like this ::   :: which is exactly where the data.xml file resides.  I figured that had to be the solution.  Still no data gets loaded.... unless I have the data.xml, banner.swf, banner_images, all in the root directory where page.php which contains the object code resides.  How can I make this seemingly easy thing work ?

Comment: have you put crossdomain.xml?

Answer (score 0):

could ou give a detailed directory structure and example xml file? the problem is probably that you are supplying incorrect relative paths in the data file as well as the incorrect path to the data.xml in your embed code, but id need examples to verify and help you solve.

Although generally speaking the easiest thing to do is use absolute paths like "/path/to/whatever" in the emebed tags and the data.xml file. Of course thats not always possible to do depending on the situation.